# 2013 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Ask Ubuntu's [third moderator election](https://askubuntu.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the three new moderators are:

[image: RolandiXor] [image: jokerdino] [image: Luis Alvarado]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://askubuntu.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/874019/0).

Comment: Congrats everyone, I look forward to flooding your inboxes with stuff to do.

Comment: @JorgeCastro ♥ :)

Comment: Nice job guys, Congrats to all the winners. Looking forward to working with each one of you.

Comment: Well done, everybody! Good luck with the job!!

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to everyone that participated and voted!.

Congratulations to Roland and Jokerdino!

I would also like to personally thank my producer, director, writers, the staff behind the scene, the music band, the dog next to the food, the other dog next to the dog next to the food. The lighting people, the cleaning lady, my family, friends, the book from Narnia, the Lord of the Ring characters, Jorge Castro (AKA Cyborg from the future), Oli (Aka... He has a Diamond), Nathan, Marco Ceppi (Aka crazy face on FB), that girl that does not like me and everyone else which I did not mention here because they are ugly ^^.

Now that the new moderators will soon receive their new found powers, some of which are:

- Doughnut shooting eyes
- Invisiblity when dead
- Ability to walk on concrete floor
- Tele..vision with cable
- Ability to breath above water
- Other powerful features!

  We will take over the world, destroy aliens and eat versions of Libreoffice that taste like double cheese burgers.

But of course, we could not have done anything if it were not for the presence of someone so honest, true to his word and a plain and simple Saint, this is Roland:

[image]

Comment: *Felicitaciones* man! Your declarations about powers gave me a little of scare :S ... Also, nice finding yours with that @RolandiXor picture, very funny. And congrats for all the new crew!!